# Convert xls to csv WITHOUT separators in Python

Tags: python, csv, xlsx, xls

I want to convert xls file to csv file, i found a code :

```
import xlrd
import unicodecsv

def xls2csv (xls_filename, csv_filename):
# Converts an Excel file to a CSV file.
# If the excel file has multiple worksheets, only the first worksheet is converted.
# Uses unicodecsv, so it will handle Unicode characters.
# Uses a recent version of xlrd, so it should handle old .xls and new .xlsx equally well.

wb = xlrd.open_workbook(xls_filename)
sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

fh = open(csv_filename,"wb")
csv_out = unicodecsv.writer(fh, encoding='utf-8')

for row_number in xrange (sh.nrows):
    csv_out.writerow(sh.row_values(row_number))

fh.close()
```

but the problem is that this code gives me a csv file like that :

[image: what i get]

and I want something like this :

[image: what i want]

as you can see I dont want "," separators I want to keep columns !

Thank you ! (Python)

Answer (score 0):

CSV is supposed to be machine readable. You can have a `,` or `;` or tab delimited, but it has to be delimited with something. It is possible you're reading it into excel wrong after the conversion.

edit: after looking closer, it seems you have commas in your data. I would recommend a tab delimiter

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand correctly but... csv stands for "Comma Separated Values", so the comma (or another kind of separator) HAS to exists.

However, you will not see the commas if you open the CSV file correctly.

Start Excel, create a new spreadsheet, click on data and get external data from text file, then follow the instruction and you will get the CSV imported in Excel with no separator.

If in doubt, have a look here: https://www.hesa.ac.uk/support/user-guides/import-csv

Dave